# Synchronizing two methods in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a class like this one:

```
public class IClass{

   public void draw(){...};  //is called periodically by the rendering thread
   public void foo(){...};    //is called asynchronously from another Thread(it could be an onTouchEvent() method for example)
}
```

I want the foo() method to wait until the draw method is finished and vice versa. How can I do this in Java?

regards

Comment: The answer is in the title of your question. Make them synchronized: `public synchronized void draw() {...};` (and same for foo). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: You are using the Hungarian notation in Java (which is rare) and using it wrong (`I` means interface, while you have a concrete class).

Comment: synchronize methods and make the object thread call foo() within while in draw().

Comment: I'm not sure if you really need to synchronize your draw method as only one single thread will access this method. However, some internal state will obviously have to. Your asynchronous `onToucheEvent()` method f.e. could add the event to a synchronized queue (java provides a one-liner therefore) and this queue is processed before/after the draw method automatically. For processing the queue you could use something like an [Exchanger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html).

Comment: Moreover, instead of traditional synchronization and object locking [Java's concurrent API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) should be preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the methods synchronized.

```
public synchronized void draw() {   System.out.println("draw"); }

public synchronized void foo() {    System.out.println("foo"); }
```

Or synchronize on the same object.

```
private static final Object syncObj = new Object();

public void draw() {
    synchronized (syncObj) {
        System.out.println("draw");
    }
}

public void foo() {
    synchronized (syncObj) {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you make syncObj static? It should synchronize the method calls over all instances, right? But that would be bad.. So can one simply remove the static modifier?

Comment: if you remove the `static`modifier each object for its own would have another syncObject, it does depend on what you want. `static` depends on all instances of that class, without on each instance of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `synchronized` on a method means the thread has to acquire the lock on the object instance before entering that method, so if you have two different methods marked synchronized the threads entering them will be contending for the same lock, and once one thread gets the lock all other threads are shut out of all methods that synchronize on that same lock. So in order for the two methods to run concurrently they would have to use different locks, like this:

```
public class IClass {

      private final Object lockDraw = new Object();
      private final Object lockFoo = new Object();

      public void draw() {
          synchronized(lockDraw) {
             //method draw
          }
      }

      public void foo() {
          synchronized(lockFoo) {
             //method foo
          }
      }
}
```

`Both methods lock the same monitor. Therefore, you can't simultaneously execute them on the same object from different threads (one of the two methods will block until the other is finished).`

Comment: your snyc objects are not `static` so each Object will have a different monitor, note that