# synchronization and synchronized block in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got a few questions about synchronization in java.

```java
public class A {

    private int i;

    public A (int t) { i = t; }

    public synchronized void increment() {
        i++;
    }

    public synchronized void decrement() {
        i--;
    }
}
```

Suppose I have a class implemented as above and I create an object (p) of type A.

I know there can only be one thread executing p.increment(), but is possible for another thread to execute p.decrement() at the same time ?

Thanks~

Comment: If you use synchronized for the two methods, only one method could be called at the same time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Synchronizing two methods in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341447/synchronizing-two-methods-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`synchronized` does not protect methods.  `synchronized` does not protect objects.  `synchronized` does one thing, and one thing only.

The way you wrote your increment method is actually just a shorthand way of writing this:

```
public void increment() {
    synchronized(this) {
        i++;
    }
}
```

This longer way of expressing it make it clear that `synchronized` is operating on `this`.

So, the one thing that `synchronized` does is:  The JVM will not allow two threads to be synchronized on the same object at the same time.

If you have an object, p, of type A, then the answer is "no".  The JVM will not allow one thread to do the increment at the same time the other thread does the decrement because both threads would be trying to synchronize on the same object, p.

On the other hand, if you have one object p and another object q, both of type A, then one thread could be in a p.increment() call while another thread is in the q.decrement() call.  That's because each thread would be synchronized on a different object, and that *is* allowed.

---

P.S.:  `synchronized` actually does one other thing that pertains to the Java concept called "Happens Before".  That's something you should learn about (Google is your friend) before you get much deeper into multi-threaded programming.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Using `synchronized` as a method modifier is equivalent to wrapping the method with `synchronized(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

No.  the synchronized will not allow multiple threads to enter the methods for an instance of the object.  Note if you have a p1 AND a p2 of class A  you could have p1.increment() running at same time p2.decrement() (etc.) is running.

Answer (score 0):

Actually since the value is wrapped into `synchronized` methods, it content is also synchronized so no, it won't be **executed** by another thread.

Note that it can be **called** by another thread.

Personally, if it is only a matter of decrements/increments, I wouldn't bother synchronizing and would simply use `Atomic values`.

[See documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

Comment: Thanks~ Yeah I know it's better to use AtomicInteger in this case, but just trying to understand how synchronization works in java.

Comment: How is "executed" different from "called"?

Comment: @jameslarge The call to the method will be done, however it will be executed only when it is allowed.